# Hide "load more" button when all items displayed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide 'load more' button when all items displayed even items are 3 or 10 or 25...just hide 'load more ' button when all items loaded

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
   
});
```

```css
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>

</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the statement [.toggle( display )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

> Use `true` to show the element or `false` to hide it.

```
$('#loadMore').click(function() {
    x = (x + 5 <= size_li) ? x + 5 : size_li;

    //Add this
    $(this).toggle(x < size_li);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  size_li = $("#myList li").size();
  x = 3;
  $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    x = (x + 5 <= size_li) ? x + 5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    $(this).toggle(x < size_li);
  });

});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
}
#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>

</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```